# =Query Funtion to Pull data from Another Sheet based on cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i am looking for some help to pull the data in Sheets based on another sheet called "ServicesOffered"

[here is the sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vFTAiRsocoIYUfei-FdAsO9PZJvqcpUoSFAAkE8M-tQ/edit#gid=1452251519)

The idea is simple: If Cell contains Yes then it should add data to WebDev sheet or SEO sheet.

Tried many different formulas but failed to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to have a column list or * after the Select; also shouldn't have curly brackets round the range or else it will treat it as an array and expect Col1, Col2, Col3 etc. in the Select instead of A, B, C etc.

```
=QUERY(
ServicesOffered!A2:C,
"SELECT * WHERE C = 'Yes' ",1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom.
Seems FILTER and QUERY both can do the same job. Interesting to know. Many Many Thanks

Comment: Hey Tom, i just noticed the formula is copying values in all sheets if it finds the value "Yes" in any of the columns of the given range. How can I add only the data to the sheet where it is required. ?

Comment: If it's a formula, it can only copy data into the place where the formula is. If you wanted to push the data into certain sheets only, you would need a script.

Comment: I was able to copy the data into a certain sheet using QUERY. here is the formula I used just as yours only changed Header 1 to 0

=QUERY(
ServicesOffered!A2:I,
"SELECT A,B WHERE C = 'x' ",0)